# AS3 Math.round issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need the variable value of 'speed' to be coming through as a whole number so it can affect the slide position of my 'BG' movieclip. After using this code (and trying many other variations), the 'round' variable only comes through as 0 or 1. (This code is all in the `ENTER FRAME` function.)

```
var speed:Number = (xspeed + yspeed) / 100;
var round:Number = Math.round(speed);

BG.gotoAndStop(speed);
texta.text = ""+(round);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're diving by 100 so there's a high likelyhood that your number is actually between 0 and 1 (if `xspeed + yspeed` is ever less than 100, `speed` will be less than 1 after dividing by 100).

What do you get when you `trace(speed)`?

Comment: oh thats because the output was around 10000 and i needed it to be within the range of 0-100. So when i have the text box show the speed variable (`texta.text = ""+(speed);`) it comes out between 0-100 which is great, but often with up to 5 decimal places...

Comment: @Dan434 That's odd. If `speed` is indeed between 0 and 100 then `round` should be as well. Are you certain of the value of `speed`? Maybe trace both `speed` and `round` at the same time and see what the values are and how they compare. Use `trace()` as opposed to setting the text in a text field.

Comment: Yeah i thought it was weird. Checked it but no difference... :/ Should I post the whole code?

Comment: @Dan434 You mean there's no difference between `speed` and `round`?

Comment: No i meant there is no change in the vaiable readings... `speed` is still 0-100 with up to 5 decimal figures, and `sound` is still flitting about between 0-1.

Comment: @Dan434 What happens if you do something like `Math.round(55.53)`.

Comment: Comes up with 56... Thanks for the help by the way, much appreciated :)

Comment: @Dan434 Interesting. That confirms that `speed` is definitely between 0 and 1. Instead of rounding, maybe try assigning the result of `speed` to an `int` instead. i.e. var `speed:int = (xspeed + yspeed) / 100;` What happens then?

Comment: That has actually solved the problem! I honestly think I tried this before and nothing happened... :/ Yeah, thanks a lot man :)